# php: call function from class but change variables that function takes in

Tags: php, class, variables

I'm calling a public static function `getSignal()` from another class, but how do I change the variable definition that is otherwise hard-coded into the function I'm calling?

```
class moo{

  public static function $getSignal($alert) {
    $my_array = array_pop($this->blah->myFunction1()->bestFunction());
    $signals = $pop[$alert];
  }
}
```

Now in another file, I'm calling this by:

```
return moo::getSignal($alert);
```

However, the problem is, I need to change `$my_array` as I call it from class `moo` slightly.  It needs to be:

```
$my_array = array_pop($this->cow->bestFunction());
```

How can I do this?? Appreciate any help or insights.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do it would be to pass `$my_array` as an argument to `getSignal()`, e.g. the method would change to something like

```
public static function getSignal($alert, array $my_array) {
    $last = array_pop($my_array);
    $signals = $pop[$alert];
}
```

It's a slightly strange example because `$my_array` isn't used in the function body. You're also using `$this` within a static context.

Assuming access to all relevant members, you would call this in the 'other' file like this:

```
return moo::getSignal($alert, $this->blah->myFunction1()->bestFunction());
```

and from within the `moo` class:

```
return self::getSignal($alert, $this->cow->bestFunction());
```

Comment: you can't use $this within public static functions?

Comment: Not because of the visibility (`public`), but because it's static. `$this` refers to the current object and so cannot be used in static functions because there is no object context. If you run your code (after removing the `$` from the beginning of the function name so it compiles!), you'll see `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context...`.

Comment: gotcha, changing to public function

Comment: i'm confused at how I would call this function from the other file, wouldn't it still be calling the same `$my_array`? when I call `return moo::getSignal($alert);`

Comment: wouldn't `$my_array = array_pop($my_array);` be recursive?

Comment: No. Why would you think that? I admit reassigning the result to the same variable is bad form though - will edit.

Answer (score 0):

if you must change what you intend changing then you must make room for another parameter to getSignal() like this

```
class moo{

  public static function $getSignal($alert,array $arrayParam) {
    $my_array = array_pop($arrayParam);
    $signals = $pop[$alert];
  }
}
```